# Easy Slider jquery -can't see the next previeous buttons

Tags: jquery, css, easyslider

I'm trying to use the easySlider jquery plugin. I want just to reproduce.

http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/01.html

I see the images in a list, but can't see Next/Previous Links.

Do I should add them to my html even they are not in the demo page?

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EasySlider.aspx.cs" Inherits="jQuery.EasySlider" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        img {
            border: none;
        }

        pre {
            display: block;
            font: 12px "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
            padding: 10px;
            border: 1px solid #bae2f0;
            background: #e3f4f9;
            margin: .5em 0;
            width: 500px;
        }

        #slider ul, #slider li {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style: none;
        }

        #slider li {
            width: 696px;
            height: 241px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        span#prevBtn {
        }

        span#nextBtn {
        }
    </style>
    <script src="easySlider1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#slider").easySlider();

        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <div id="slider">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/30"><img src="images/slider/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/7"><img src="images/slider/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/25"><img src="images/slider/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/26"><img src="images/slider/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://templatica.com/preview/27"><img src="images/slider/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <a id="nextBtn"></a>
            <a id="prevBtn"></a>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

With that plugin the element is generated by the code.  Make sure you've uploaded the images and check your css to be sure you haven't overridden anything essential.  Can you post the code in an example so I can see what's going on?

UPDATE:

In line 65 and 66 you don't have any of the rules listed for the

```
span#prevBtn{}
span#nextBtn{}
```

I believe, at first glance, you're missing all of this code:

```
#prevBtn, #nextBtn,
    #slider1next, #slider1prev{ 
        display:block;
        width:35px;
        height:35px;
        position:absolute;
        left:-15px;
        top:110px;
        z-index:1000;
        }   
    #nextBtn, #slider1next{ 
        left:940px;
        }                                                       
    #prevBtn a, #nextBtn a{  
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        width:53px;
        height:53px;
        background:url(../images/btn_prev.png) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }   
    #nextBtn a, #slider1next a{ 
        background:url(../images/btn_next.png) no-repeat 0 0;   
        }
```

Depending on the width and height of your div, you'll play with the `left` attribute to position the btns correctly.

Comment: Hey d2burke,u have the code.and u can test the original link http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/01.html

Comment: In line 65 and 66 you don't have any of the rules listed for the 

`span#prevBtn{}
span#nextBtn{}`

Comment: Hey d2burke,actually i don't want images for next and previous.just links:next previous.Me i just to reproduce the page  cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/01.html

Comment: what are nextBtn,prevBtn.Do we should add them.or they are generated by the js script.Why they didn't explain what they are?

Comment: in http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.5/01.html.It is left like span#prevBtn{} span#nextBtn{}`

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the text in your anchor tags i.e.,

```
<a id="nextBtn"></a>    
<a id="prevBtn"></a>
```

Add some text to your anchor tags

```
<a id="nextBtn"> Next </a>    
<a id="prevBtn"> Previous </a>
```

Comment: This plugin actually creates the `nextBtn` and `prevBtn`.  It only requires that you create the unordered list with the right id `#slider` and fill it with `<li>`s